# OES/EXT/ARB_framebuffer_object

Tags: opengl-es

What are the differences between OES/EXT/ARB_framebuffer_object extensions. Can all of these extensions be used with OpenGLES 1.1 or OpenGLES2.0 applications? Or are there any guidlines w.r.t what extension to be used with which version of GLESx.x?

Answer (score 1):

OK After some googling i found the below piece of info...

1. GLES FBO 
   a. are core under GLES2 
   b. under GLES1, exposed via the extension GL_OES_framebuffer_object, 
     under which API entry point are glFunctionNameOES
2. OpenGL 1.x/2.x with GL_EXT_framebuffer_object 
   under which API entry points are glSomeFunctionEXT
3. OpenGL 3.x FBO/GL_ARB_framebuffer_object 
   under GL 3.x, FBO's are core and API points are glSomeFunction 
   also, there is a "backport" exttention for GL 2.x, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object 
   API entry point are glSomeFunction(). Note the lack of EXT or ARB suffix.

   Token naming: 
    1a. no suffix 
    1b. _OES

   1. _EXT
   2. no suffix.

   fortuantely, the token names map to the same values 
   Additionally, their usage is different: 
   1a,1b: Depth and stencil buffers are attatched sperately as render buffers 
         or also possibly supported is attatching both as one buffer with 
         the extension GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil.
         Depth buffer is defualt at 16bits!

   2,3: The spec allows for attatching depth and stencil seperately, but 
       all consumer level desktop hardware does not support this, rather to 
       attatch both a stencil and depth buffer calls for a depth-stencil texture. 
          2. extension GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, type is GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_EXT 
          3. part of the FBO spec, type is GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8 
       Note: the value of the tokens GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8 and  GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_EXT 
             are the same.

   Issues with GL_EXT_framebuffer_object 
   a) GL_EXT_framebuffer_object might not be listed in GL 3.x contexts because 
   FBO's are core. 
   b) also, if have a GL 2.x context with newer hardware, possible that 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object is not listed but GL_ARB_framebuffer_object is

   Differences of capabilities: 
   FBO support via 3.x/GL_ARB_framebuffer_object allows for color buffer attathments 
   to have different types and resoltions, additionally, MSAA and blit functionality
   is part  of 3.x core and part of  GL_ARB_framebuffer_object.

   FBO support via GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, both blit and MSAA support 
   are exposed as separate extensions.